# Call the class without clicking on the input

Tags: javascript

I have the following input where I use the `Price` class with the `maskMoney` library.

```js
var linha1 = ``;

linha1 += `<div class="form-group col-md-2">  
                        <input type="text" class="form-control1 alinha Preco" value="5200" readonly="true">
                        <span class="form-highlight"></span>
                        <span class="form-bar"></span>
                        <label class="label1" for="Total">Total do Orçamento</label>        
                      </div>`;
            
$("#ficliente1").html(linha1);

$('.Preco').maskMoney({ decimal: '.', thousands: ' ', precision: 2 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>


<form role="form" id="ficliente1" style="margin-top: 2%;">

</form>
```

The problem is that for the class to be applied I need to have an input action. I intended that without clicking on the input the 5200 would be 52.00 right away.

Comment: "I intended that without clicking" if not on click, then when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can focus the input programmatically:

```js
var linha1 = ``;

linha1 += `<div class="form-group col-md-2">  
                        <input type="text" class="form-control1 alinha Preco" onload="valorp()" value="5200" readonly="true">
                        <span class="form-highlight"></span>
                        <span class="form-bar"></span>
                        <label class="label1" for="Total">Total do Orçamento</label>        
                      </div>`;
            
$("#ficliente1").html(linha1);

$('.Preco').maskMoney({ decimal: '.', thousands: ' ', precision: 2 });
$('.Preco').focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>


<form role="form" id="ficliente1" style="margin-top: 2%;">

</form>
```